# Duplicate request sent at fixed time interval on tomcat 5.5 mod_jk connector

Tags: tomcat

Configuration on tomcat -

mod_jk connector 
worker.properties -

```
worker.list=tomcat
worker.tomcat.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat.host=localhost
worker.tomcat.port=7615
```

Problem Statement - 
For heavy load data, when the browser sends a request to my application, after exactly 3 minutes i can see another duplicate request being sent to my application.

I tried the following things - 
1) For small load data, I tried putting thread.sleep for 5 minutes, and the result was duplicate request sent to my application.

2) I also tried configuring the worker.properties with reply_timeout, socket_timeout. But it keeps on sending duplicate request.

3) I also deployed my application on Tomcat 6, but I got the same result.

The mod_jk logs -

```
[Mon Nov 12 11:09:04 2012] [23690:1908194448] [info] init_jk::mod_jk.c (3183): mod_jk/1.2.28 initialized
[Mon Nov 12 11:15:32 2012] [23692:1908194448] [info] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1496): (tomcat) all endpoints are disconnected, detected by connect check (1), cping (0), send (0)
[Mon Nov 12 11:15:54 2012] [23797:1908194448] [info] ajp_process_callback::jk_ajp_common.c (1788): Writing to client aborted or client network problems
[Mon Nov 12 11:15:54 2012] [23797:1908194448] [info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2447): (tomcat) sending request to tomcat failed (unrecoverable), because of client write error (attempt=1)
[Mon Nov 12 11:15:54 2012] [23797:1908194448] [info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2608): Aborting connection for worker=tomcat
[Mon Nov 12 11:16:31 2012] [23694:1908194448] [info] ajp_send_request::jk_ajp_common.c (1496): (tomcat) all endpoints are disconnected, detected by connect check (1), cping (0), send (0)
```

I do not get any error in the access.log.

Could there be a network connection issue? If yes, then what is the possible solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: how are you processing the request ? are you using AJAX ?

Comment: No..I am using the usual action class to process my request.